# Need to grep a string from a line in a variable and store it in another variable

Tags: perl

I have a variable `$abc` that contains the line like below:

```
abc.txt ->  check a/b/c test
```

I need to get `abc.txt` in another variable say `$bcd` and `a/b/c` in the variable say `$xyz`. I have the regex to do so but I don't know how I can do it using perl as in my knowledge perl grep and perl map can be used on arrays only not variables.

Comment: *I have the regex to do so* Should probably include it in your question, then.

Comment: You might also want to read https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions

Comment: You can store match groups in variables like this: `my $str = "1 2"; my ($i, $j) = $str =~ /(\d+) (\d+)/;`

Comment: You can use split `my($bcd,$xyz) = (split(' ', $abc))[0,3];`, or if you insist on regex then `my($bcd,$xyz) = $abc =~ /(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)/;`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```perl
my ($bcd) = split(/\s*->\s*/, $abc, 2);
```

```perl
my $bcd = $abc =~ s/\s*->.*//sr;
```

```perl
my ($bcd) = $abc =~ /^(?:(?!\s*->).)*)/s;
```

```perl
my ($bcd) = $abc =~ /^(.*?)\s*->/s;
```

All but the last returns the entire input string if there's no `->`.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I used the first one and it worked. Can you please let me know what is 2 doing in that statement ?

Comment: Not much. Prevents splitting on any subsequent `->`